# There is no Gâteaux-Differential of $F:L^1(I)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, F(x):=|u|_1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck showing that $F$ as above doesn't have a  Gâteaux-differential. We got a hint from our professor to compute $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} (F(u+hv)-F(u))/h=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int\limits_I\frac{|u+h\,v|-|u|}{h}dx.$$

I am not entirely sure how to do that in this situation because $|.|$ isn't differentiable.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: it is easiest to consider $u = 0$.

Comment: Is the problem then that our functional isn't linear?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Certainly the Gateaux dervitative exists for some $u$ in some directions.

Comment: @zhw.: What do you mean by "some directions"? For me, a function is Gateaux differentiable, if the directional derivative exists for all directions and is linear w.r.t. the direction.

Comment: By definition the limit needs to be $A_u(v)$ where $A:L^p(I) \rightarrow (L^p(I))'$ But then $A_0(v)=|v|_1$ so non linear.

Comment: I was referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gâteaux_derivative#Definition

Comment: No,  $A_0(v)\ne \|v\|_1.$ $A_0(v)$ simply doesn't exist if if $\|v\|_1> 0.$

Comment: @zhw.: This is not true. The directional derivative exists everywhere and in all directions. See the answer below.

Comment: I disagree; clearly the OP has $h\to 0,$ which is standard, not $h\to 0^+.$

Answer (score 0):

First, we consider the absolute value function $f : x \mapsto |x|$. Then, it is clear that $f$ is directionally differentiable at all points in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, we consider $u,v \in L^1(I)$. We have to consider $t \searrow 0$ in
$$\int_I \frac{f(u(x)+t\,v(x)) - f(u(x))}{t} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Since $f$ is directionally differentiable, it is clear that the integrand converges pointwise to $f'(u(x), v(x))$. Moreover, since $f$ is globally Lipschitz continuous, the integrand is bounded by $|v(x)|$, which is integrable. Hence, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem, and obtain
$$\lim_{t\searrow 0}\int_I \frac{f(u(x)+t\,v(x)) - f(u(x))}{t} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_I f'(u(x),v(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Hence, $F$ is everywhere directionally differentiable in all directions. However, it fails to be linear if $u(x) = 0$ on some set of positive measure.

Comment: You are using an unusual definition of directional derivative; it's almost always as $t\to 0,$ not $t\to 0^+.$

Comment: In my field of research (optimization), the directional derivative is always $t \searrow 0$. I have had a look into my standard books, and none of them had $t \to 0$.

Comment: And all my books (up to the old Ioffe&Tichomirov) define: "Gateaux = directional derivative exists and is linear and bounded w.r.t. the direction".